# Contar ciertas filas en un datagridview

Tags: c#, windows-forms

quiero contar ciertas filas de mi datagridview, por el momento solo se que `dgt.RowCount` cuenta el total de filas del datagridview, en mi caso quiero contar filas que cumplan una condicion. las filas  tienen un apartado llamado "Promedio" en ella hay valores enteros, quiero contar solo las filas en el que el apartado de promedio sea >=70 y posteriormente llevar ese valor a un label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar Linq

```
using System.Linq;

...

int count = dataGrid.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Count(row => row.Cells["Promedio"].Value >= 70);
```

El cast a `DataGridViewRow` es necesario para poder hacer queries de Linq, ya que la clase `DataGridViewRowCollection` no expone la interfaz `IEnumerable<DataGridViewRow>`.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, solo que en mi caso tuve que añadir "(int)" antes del row.cell

Answer (score 0):

He estado buscando algo de información [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=net-5.0), [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rows?view=net-5.0) y [Aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.cells?view=net-5.0) y creo que deberías hacer un bucle parecido a este que te escribiré en pseudocódigo:

```
DataGridView dgt;
var rows = dgt.Rows;
int count =0;

foreach(var r in rows){
    if(r.cells[Promedio].Value >=){
         ++count;
    }
}
lablel.Text= count;
```

Espero que te haya servido, recuerda que es pseudocódigo y debes adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Guíate por los enlaces.